# OAUTH for twitter and django

Tags: django, twitter-oauth

I am using django-twitter oauth . But i can not understand what is CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECTRET? is it username , password or not ! Please anyone help me.

Nazmul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: When you sign up to use Twitter authentication, Twitter will give you these.

Long answer: When you sign up to use Twitter OAUTH, you must register as a Twitter application.  (Registration can be found [here](http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new).)  You will be given these two keys.  The SECRET you keep secret (duh); it's what you use to pass messages back and forth between your application and Twitter securely.  The KEY is used to sign messages from the user to you and Twitter, and establishes a trust relationship within the triangle of you, Twitter, and the user's browser.